# In which banking institute was Soren Kierkegaard a customer?

Tags: 19th-century, denmark

Is there any information about which bank the danish philosopher Søren Kierkegaard (1813-1855) used in Copenhagen?

I might think it is ['Sparekassen for Kjøbenhavn og Omegn'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparekassen_for_Kj%C3%B8benhavn_og_Omegn), literally 'The Savings Bank for Copenhagen and Its Vicinity', which can be traced to the big nordic bank '[Nordea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nordea)' in our time.

I can see that some of the board members of that bank were Jonas Collin and 
dr. theol. J. P. Mynster, and they have a relation to Kierkegaard. [External link](http://www.coneliand.dk/Danmarks%20aeldste%20forretninger/DAEF%20500-599/Side_563_Spar_-_Spar.html?fbclid=IwAR0QgBZEC0XBJ8QkFSYiu4tjVcHjvmgYxYDNmGnzViyY2DAH07v0P317mKQ)

Answer (score 1):

At one time Søren Kierkegaard kept his money at the National Bank in a locked chest where one of his brothers-in-law worked, and his brother-in-law had the only key. It's not really clear if this was a bank account but it doesn't look like it (more a private arrangement).

The money was in packets and came from an inheritance. Kierkegaard did not want to invest it as he said it was against his religious convictions, according to a book called *[Encounters with Kierkegaard: A Life as Seen by His Contemporaries](https://books.google.ca/books?redir_esc=y&id=D9kKuc9xWLcC&q=ban#v=onepage&q=bank&f=false)*. From time to time, he came and took a packet. This happened between about 1844 and 1854.

Apart from this, I can't find anything else on his banking arrangements.